# Place HTML element in the bottom of web page

Tags: html, css

How to place `HTML` element for `Surname` input in the bottom of `HTML` page?

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    Name <input value ="aaa" >
    Surname <input value = "ccc" >
</body>
</html>
```

Currently it is placed at the top of the page . What would be a better solution for making it go to the bottom of the page than using many `<br>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

First wrap your label and input in some container and add a class for it(e.g. .custom_input) and then after the css for your new element:
`body{ position:relative; }` 
`.custom_input{position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;}`